# Installing scikit-learn in a docker container fails with cmake / ninja errors

Tags: python, docker, scikit-learn, containers

I am trying to run a simple API **on a raspberry pi** that has a backend powered by a sklearn regression model. After training I save it and later use it like this (only the use part will later be in the container):

```
import joblib
joblib.dump(gradient_boost, "../app/model.pkl")
model = joblib.load(self.filename)
```

This is my requirements.txt: The version numbers are the ones I have on my dev machine (windows), I got them through `pip list`

```
click==8.1.3
fastapi==0.95.0
h11==0.12.0
pydantic==1.10.7
starlette==0.26.1
uvicorn==0.21.1
numpy==1.23.1
joblib==1.2.0
scikit-learn==1.2.1
requests==2.27.1
```

And the Dockerfile:

```
FROM arm32v7/python:3.9-buster

COPY ./app /app/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN /usr/local/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uvicorn", "app.main:app", "--host=0.0.0.0", "--reload"]
```

docker build runs fine if i remove the scikit-learn requirement. However I am then presented with `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'` at runtime. Adding it results in:

```
 > [6/6] RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt:
#10 8.137 Collecting click==8.1.3
#10 8.397   Downloading click-8.1.3-py3-none-any.whl (96 kB)
#10 8.486      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 96.6/96.6 kB 3.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 10.12 Collecting fastapi==0.95.0
#10 10.17   Downloading fastapi-0.95.0-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
#10 10.24      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.1/57.1 kB 1.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 10.50 Collecting h11==0.12.0
#10 10.55   Downloading h11-0.12.0-py3-none-any.whl (54 kB)
#10 10.63      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 54.9/54.9 kB 2.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 13.89 Collecting pydantic==1.10.7
#10 13.94   Downloading pydantic-1.10.7-py3-none-any.whl (157 kB)
#10 14.01      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 157.2/157.2 kB 4.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 14.69 Collecting starlette==0.26.1
#10 14.73   Downloading starlette-0.26.1-py3-none-any.whl (66 kB)
#10 14.79      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 66.9/66.9 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 15.43 Collecting uvicorn==0.21.1
#10 15.47   Downloading uvicorn-0.21.1-py3-none-any.whl (57 kB)
#10 15.53      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 57.8/57.8 kB 2.7 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 20.75 Collecting numpy==1.23.1
#10 20.81   Downloading numpy-1.23.1.tar.gz (10.7 MB)
#10 23.05      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 10.7/10.7 MB 4.9 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 33.57   Installing build dependencies: started
#10 64.95   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#10 64.98   Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#10 75.34   Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#10 75.38   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#10 82.99   Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#10 83.48 Collecting joblib==1.2.0
#10 83.53   Downloading joblib-1.2.0-py3-none-any.whl (297 kB)
#10 83.63      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 298.0/298.0 kB 6.3 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 85.66 Collecting scikit-learn==1.2.1
#10 85.71   Downloading scikit-learn-1.2.1.tar.gz (7.3 MB)
#10 86.77      ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 7.3/7.3 MB 7.2 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 92.90   Installing build dependencies: started
#10 174.4   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 456.7   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 606.0   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 760.1   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 820.4   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 881.0   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 943.7   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1004.3   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1076.6   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1153.7   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1315.9   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1397.5   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1500.5   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1675.1   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1769.3   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1858.2   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1930.9   Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.2   Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#10 1983.4   error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4   × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#10 1983.4   │ exit code: 1
#10 1983.4   ╰─> [85 lines of output]
#10 1983.4       Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.10" and platform_system == "Windows" and platform_python_implementation != "PyPy"' don't match your environment
#10 1983.4       Collecting setuptools<60.0
#10 1983.4         Downloading setuptools-59.8.0-py3-none-any.whl (952 kB)
#10 1983.4            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 952.8/952.8 kB 6.1 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 1983.4       Collecting wheel
#10 1983.4         Downloading wheel-0.40.0-py3-none-any.whl (64 kB)
#10 1983.4            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 64.5/64.5 kB 2.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 1983.4       Collecting Cython>=0.29.24
#10 1983.4         Using cached Cython-0.29.34-py2.py3-none-any.whl (988 kB)
#10 1983.4       Collecting oldest-supported-numpy
#10 1983.4         Downloading oldest_supported_numpy-2022.11.19-py3-none-any.whl (4.9 kB)
#10 1983.4       Collecting scipy>=1.3.2
#10 1983.4         Downloading scipy-1.10.1.tar.gz (42.4 MB)
#10 1983.4            ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 42.4/42.4 MB 5.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: started
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: still running...
#10 1983.4         Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#10 1983.4         Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#10 1983.4         Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#10 1983.4         Installing backend dependencies: started
#10 1983.4         Installing backend dependencies: finished with status 'error'
#10 1983.4         error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4         × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
#10 1983.4         │ exit code: 1
#10 1983.4         ╰─> [34 lines of output]
#10 1983.4             Collecting ninja>=1.8.2
#10 1983.4               Downloading ninja-1.11.1.tar.gz (27 kB)
#10 1983.4               Installing build dependencies: started
#10 1983.4               Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'
#10 1983.4               Getting requirements to build wheel: started
#10 1983.4               Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'done'
#10 1983.4               Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): started
#10 1983.4               Preparing metadata (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'done'
#10 1983.4             Collecting patchelf>=0.11.0
#10 1983.4               Downloading patchelf-0.17.2.1-py2.py3-none-manylinux_2_17_armv7l.manylinux2014_armv7l.musllinux_1_1_armv7l.whl (381 kB)
#10 1983.4                  ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 381.1/381.1 kB 5.8 MB/s eta 0:00:00
#10 1983.4             Building wheels for collected packages: ninja
#10 1983.4               Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): started
#10 1983.4               Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml): finished with status 'error'
#10 1983.4               error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4               × Building wheel for ninja (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
#10 1983.4               │ exit code: 1
#10 1983.4               ╰─> [9 lines of output]
#10 1983.4                   Traceback (most recent call last):
#10 1983.4                     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4xmyfmm/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 645, in setup
#10 1983.4                       cmkr = cmaker.CMaker(cmake_executable)
#10 1983.4                     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4xmyfmm/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 148, in __init__
#10 1983.4                       self.cmake_version = get_cmake_version(self.cmake_executable)
#10 1983.4                     File "/tmp/pip-build-env-r4xmyfmm/overlay/lib/python3.9/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 105, in get_cmake_version
#10 1983.4                       raise SKBuildError(msg) from err
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4                   Problem with the CMake installation, aborting build. CMake executable is cmake
#10 1983.4                   [end of output]
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4               note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 1983.4               ERROR: Failed building wheel for ninja
#10 1983.4             Failed to build ninja
#10 1983.4             ERROR: Could not build wheels for ninja, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
#10 1983.4             [end of output]
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4         note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 1983.4       error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4       × pip subprocess to install backend dependencies did not run successfully.
#10 1983.4       │ exit code: 1
#10 1983.4       ╰─> See above for output.
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4       note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 1983.4       [end of output]
#10 1983.4
#10 1983.4   note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
#10 1983.5 error: subprocess-exited-with-error
#10 1983.5
#10 1983.5 × pip subprocess to install build dependencies did not run successfully.
#10 1983.5 │ exit code: 1
#10 1983.5 ╰─> See above for output.
#10 1983.5
#10 1983.5 note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
```

It should later run on a raspberry pi 4, thats why i chose a arm32v7 base image. I have the feeling that this is the issue, as similar issues also occured with e.g. numpy when I was using slim or alpine images. Any suggestion on how to get it to work?